# Identical Android admob unit only showing in one of two apps

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I have released two android apps weeks ago, each containing the same admob unit.

However, only one is showing ads, while the other does not.
I tried to create new ads units and put them on the app that not showing ads, but it was still not working. What could be a reason?

Comment: Perhaps you should do some diff between the applications. May be you have miss out on something. If not, then you should be writing the steps you did in the application, hope we can help then.

Comment: I take some time (around 24 hour) for a newly created ad id to show ads. So, if it is new, you better wait for a while

Comment: A more appropriated stackexchange sub is https://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you set up admob ads, you can use only one app associated with admob app.

When you initialize ads, you do this:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "Your App ID");
```

This instructs AdMob that this app is the app which should be linked with admob and show ads, other apps with the same unit but registered after the first app will not be able to get ads available!

So, the conclusion is: you can use only one app with one admob registered app!